# Nginx Reverse Proxy Takes ~15 Seconds For Page to Load

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

This is my first time using nginx, so I don't really know if this is to be expected. Without nginx, the page should typically start up at around less than 5 seconds. I checked the error logs, and there doesn't seem to be any errors.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        root /var/www/html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


server {
        # SSL Configuration
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        # HTTP Basic Auth
        auth_basic "Private Property";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        # Proxy Settings
        proxy_buffers 32 4m;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 25m;
        proxy_buffer_size 512k;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
        client_body_buffer_size 4m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referrer;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }
        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you have a delay, you first need to look at your web application, not nginx. nginx doesn't introduce artificial delays to frustrate people. It just passes on to your app.

Comment: Have you already tried increasing your timeout values from 300 to like 900?

Comment: I'll try doing that, thanks Lukas

Comment: Increasing the timeout values will not change the result. The value is in seconds, which would correspond to 5 and 15 minutes respectively. Since the page loads, and does so in far less than that time, it's not a timeout issue. As @MichaelHampton writes, look at the application first.

Comment: What @MichaelHampton said.  Increasing the timeout values just increases the time nginx will wait for a response from the backend.  300 seconds is 5 minutes.  If it takes that long, you have an issues outside of nginx.

Comment: @Too Short yeah you are right. Somehow I thought timeout isn't specified in seconds. My bad

Comment: If you want to rule out any nginx issues, you could try redirecting to a static page, or one with minimal code such as a hello-world. I highly doubt the issue is nginx but it doesn't hurt to doublecheck to rule it out in your troubleshooting. Additionally, a five second page load even without nginx is excessively slow in today's Internet. Unless there's a really good reason for it taking so long, you may want to take a second look at your application for that reason alone.

Comment: I have similar issue. The dynatrace shows that nginx proxy call takes exact 15 secs. All members of SRE insist that nginx proxy wouldnt add 15 secs. I am trying to figure out where this exact 15 secs gets added. This gets added to APIs intermittently and I dont see any specific pattern to it